# My RecyclerView keeps repeating the same item (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So I created a RecyclerView to generate beverage items and for some reason my recycler veiw keeps on repeating the first item.

I tried using

```
       inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View)  : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
```

while using

```
       holder.itemView.text_view1.text = user.name 
       holder.itemView.text_view2.text = user.name 
       holder.itemView.text_View3.text = user.name
```

and the the results are the same.

What's causing the repetition?

BeverageAdapter.kt

```
 class BeverageAdapter(val List:ArrayList<Beverage>) 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<BeverageAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

  class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val textViewName2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view1) as TextView
    val texViewName3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view2) as TextView
    val textViewHello = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_View3) as TextView


}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_activity, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return List.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {


    val user: Beverage = List[position]



    holder.textViewName2.text = user.name
    holder.texViewName3.text = user.name
    holder.textViewHello.text = user.name


}

}
```

Beverage.kt

```
data class Beverage(val name: String)
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.item_recycler_view)


    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(this))

    val users = ArrayList<Beverage> ()

    users.add(Beverage("Coke"))
    users.add(Beverage("Gingerale"))
    users.add(Beverage("Rootbeer"))

    val adapter = BeverageAdapter(users)

    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use 3 different `TextView` .
Just use single `TextView` and set it in Adapter.

```
 RecyclerView.Adapter<BeverageAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

  class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val textViewName1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view1) as TextView



}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_activity, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return List.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {


    val user: Beverage = List[position]



    holder.textViewName1.text = user.name



}

}
```

In `RecyclerView` basically you create one view and it repeats as many as data is there.

Comment: Right... Initially I tried using one view but I forgot you have to scroll down to see the rest of the names... Other than that thank you.